# Best way to remove duplicate value from an int array without using an extra array?

Tags: c#

I need to remove duplicate value from an int array without using an extra array and after removing duplicate value from array how can i resize the length of array?

eg:-

int []arr = new int [] {1,2,1,3,3,5,6,1,3,2,8}    //array length is 11

after removing duplicate value output should be as {1,2,3,5,6,8} // array length is 6

Is it possible then how??

**I am not allowed to use predefined methods, need to perform with proper logic only.

Comment: Why can't you do a `arr = arr.Distinct().ToArray()` ?

Comment: this question was asked in a interview.

Comment: That uses a predefined method and an extra array.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally you can't: arrays are a fixed size within .NET. You can't resize them.

You could potentially keep a separate variable to indicate the "used" portion of the array, ending up with an array of (say) { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } and a "used length" of 6. It's not clear what aspect you're interested in when it comes to performance, other than avoiding using an extra array. For example, you could sort the array, then walk along and every time you come across consecutive equal elements, shuffle the remainder up one value.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon has mentioned you can not resize array. The best approach is use a Hashset.

If you are not allowed to use Hashset, sort them. But here you are supposed to create a new array to hold result.